# GitHub for Windows: Login Failed

Tags: git, github

I was using the [git-scm](http://git-scm.com) client for a long time now, and saw a GitHub for Windows client. "Why not give it a try?"

I deleted git-scm with CCleaner and then installed this client. On the login phase, it says: "Login failed. Unable to retreive your user info from the server. A proxy server might be interfering with the request."

I don't use any proxy. What can be wrong?

**UPD:** Oh, I forgot to say, I'm using Windows 8 x64

Comment: Personal experience here, but I've had bad experiences with GitHub for Windows; the moment things don't work quite the way it expects them to work, you're left scrabbling around for the command-line tools. Use GitExtensions or similar if you like having a GUI.

Comment: Yep, I'm also happy with the CLI interface enough. But did you see that? All that good-looking buttons... I was bribed by the serpent tempter.

Comment: To me this seems more like a question for the [Github support team](https://github.com/contact) as this is their product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is closed. Just reinstalled the app 3 times. Always helps.

**Edit:** there was a problem with ssh keys. They were created, but they didn't push to GitHub, so we couldn't login with them. Just in case, if someone has this problem too.

Comment: Just in case, as it seems to be, there was some problem with SSH keys. First 2 times, it wasn't installed properly. Actualy, it wasn't even installed.

Comment: I was going to recommend reinstalling twice. Just as well I didn't, that wouldn't have stood a chance of fixing your problem and I'd have just looked stupid!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem, where I could not connect to github for windows client and get all the time login failed even if credentials are correct and no proxy is in place. 
To fix it try to install **Microsoft .NET FRAMEWORK 4.5.1**

Comment: Ferpeetsake, Why?!?!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably .NET framework issue. Install patch from Microsoft.
This solved the issue for me.
Download patch from here:
[.Net Patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you installed the patch. The patch is for existing .Net framwork installation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that you have to uninstall the existing GitHub application and then have to install .Net Framework later Github application.

Comment: Yes.Uninstall Github application and Install .Net Framework patch and then restart your pc. Once done, install Github. This might work.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem.I try to update .Net framwork or reinstall github,but it doesn't work for me.Finally,I solve this problem through close the goagent.This solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked to actually change my password to a more complex one. My old password was 7 chars, new one was 15 chars with capital/lower letters and numbers.