# GitHub for Windows: login failed with .Net 4.5.2

Tags: .net, authentication, github-for-windows

So I recently updated .NET on my computer to 4.5.2 - and I think this is causing an error with GitHub for Windows.  As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336297/github-for-windows-login-failed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414291/login-failed-in-github-for-window), you can install patches, make sure certain DLLs aren't corrupted, re-install, etc.  I have done all of these, and none have worked.  All of these other questions are also older, and before 4.5.2 was released.  For full clarification, the versions of .NET I have installed are:

- 4.5.2
- 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack
- 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
- 4.5.1 SDK

I have reinstalled at least 3 times, and the app still does not work.  It was working fine until I upgraded .Net to 4.5.2.  What do I do from here?

Another symptom I am having is that every repository I try to view says `Failure looking for HEAD in this repository`, which I take to mean that it cannot access the remote repository.  I imagine this is because of the same reason that login is failing.  However, if I open the repository in Git Bash, everything is working fine - I can see the remote, push to it, pull from it, everything.  The issue lies somewhere within the GitHub for Windows client.  I just don't know where...

Comment: Maybe contact github with [their contact form here](https://github.com/contact) or their [support (at) github.com email](https://windows.github.com/help.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I submitted the question (mostly copy-pasted from this question).  If they respond with an answer, I'll post it here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this question, GitHub for Windows released an update that has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I had GitHub before and I uninstalled it for some reason. Then Microsoft updates came and with them the .NET Framework 
4.5.2.

What worked for me was the uninstall suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23656691/2448645) referencing the [help from GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/uninstalling-github-for-windows) which means  just "files left behind on your system"

> ...try to re-install the GitHub for Windows app, make sure that you
>   uninstall it completely by manually erasing the following directories:
>
> `%LocalAppData%\GitHub` and `%AppData%\GitHub`
>
> More information on the unistall procedure on:
>   https://help.github.com/articles/uninstalling-github-for-windows

Give it a try. Maybe it'll help you too.

Comment: I had tried that, and it hadn't worked.  I submitted a bug report to them, and they actually released an update that fixed the issue.